# why chrome driver is not working in @Before?

Tags: java, unit-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit

I have a simple code

```
  public class PageAvailable {
            @Test
            public void test() {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/JARs/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
                WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
                driver.get("https://....net");
                System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
                driver.close();
            }}
```

above code is working fine
Now i want this code in more structure way

```
public class PageAvailable {
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
@Before
public void be(){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/JARs/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
    driver.get("....net");

}
@Test
public void test() {
    driver.get("https://...net");
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
}
@After
public void af(){
driver.close();
}}
```

I am getting following error after executing above code

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable
>   must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more
>   information, see
>   https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest
>   version can be downloaded from
>   http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html     at
>   com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:199)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:109)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:32)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:296)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:116)
>     at sample.PageAvailable.(PageAvailable.java:12)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:266)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:263)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

I think something is missing from my side.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebDriver object initialization should happen after the 'webdriver.chrome.driver' property is set.

```
public class PageAvailable {
WebDriver driver;
@Before
public void be(){

//Set Chromedriver Path
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/Users/JARs/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");

// initialize ChromeDriver instance with the chromdriver exe as set in above line.
driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.get("....net");

}
@Test
public void test() {
 //Load your URL
driver.get("https://...net");
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
}
@After
public void af(){
driver.close();
}}
```

Other option that you can use is, in Environment variable set chromedriver.exe path, in that case no need to set system property.

Answer (score 4):

WebDriver initialization `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();`
 happens prior to `@Before`, so driver starts **without** the configuration from `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",...)`.

Therefore, `driver.get("....net");` fails.

Instead, try something like this:

```
WebDriver driver;

@Before
public void before(){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/JARs/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("....net");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That makes sense -
The ChromeDriver is instantiated when PageAvailable is instantiated, and only the system proprty is set.
I think if you instantiate ChromeDriver in the @Before section (possibly layzily to avoid instantiating it oer test method) - that might solve your problem.